# How to detect drag initiated in another widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Im sorry if the title seems off, I couldn't find a better way to frame it. I have a grid of containers on the screen, and I want to be able to draw on the screen selecting and dragging across the screen. I read about the `GestureDetector` class but it only detects gesture that starts in one widget, I can do a `onPanDown`, `onPanUpdate`,`onPanEnd` but that just gives me the co-ordinates of the cursor, and I didn't feel like it was the most elegant way to do it.(I might be wrong).
 
The Block Class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class Block extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlockState createState() => _BlockState();
}

class _BlockState extends State<Block> {
  Color boxColor = Colors.white;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (boxColor == Colors.blueGrey[900])
          boxColor = Colors.white;
        else
          boxColor = Colors.blueGrey[900];
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        width: 20,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: boxColor,
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: 1,
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PathFinding Class: (Painting the blocks in a grid):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'Block.dart';

class PathFinding extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PathFindingState createState() => _PathFindingState();
}

class _PathFindingState extends State<PathFinding> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<List<Widget>> grid = [
      ...List.generate(
          40, (index) => [...List.generate(40, (index) => Block())])
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          ...grid.map((e) => Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [...e],
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a callback as a parameter from your `_PathFindingState`, whenevr you are creating a `Block`.

First, add 2 extra params to your `Block` that can be passed while creating it.

```
class Block extends StatefulWidget {

  final void onTap;   // The function from the parent to be called
  final int id;      // An id that is unique to this Block

  Block({ this.onTap, this.id });

  @override
  _BlockState createState() => _BlockState();
}
```

Then, in your `_BlockState`, whenever a `tap` is detected, call the new function to inform the `Block` class, which will then inform the `_PathFindingState` class.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    if (boxColor == Colors.blueGrey[900])
      boxColor = Colors.white;
    else
      boxColor = Colors.blueGrey[900];
    setState(() {});

    widget.onTap(widget.id); // This line will call the `onTap` function that is present in the `Block`
  },
```

Finally, in your `_PathFindingState`,

```
class _PathFindingState extends State<PathFinding> {

  void onTap (int id) {
     // A Block with `id` = id has been tapped,
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<List<Widget>> grid = [
      ...List.generate(
          40, (index) => [...List.generate(40, 
            (index) => Block(id: index, onTap: onTap) // Pass index as id and the onTap function
      )])
    ];
```

This architecture can be followed for any `Gesture` that has been detected on any `Block` and you will receive the callback in the `_PathFindingState` class and you can do whatever you want with it.